# How to Display Page Excerpts in WordPress Themes

Tags: wordpress

my search result doesn't show excerpt content of pages on WordPress it only show for the post 
advise please

Comment: There is no excerpt for pages in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
?>
```

Adds excerpt support for the 'Page' post type. Paste this code into your themes `functions.php` file (ref http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)